# Limit number of cells returned from Bigtable query in Go

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

Is it possible to limit the number of cells (not rows) returned from a Bigtable query in Go? I see a RowFilter to limit number of rows, but not actual number of cells.

Comment: We'll be adding this in the next few days, hang tight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-go/commit/9a38b472ef29179890c9d5f9d4b46621ef83c03d) commit, there are 3 ways to limit # of cells returned:

```
// LatestNFilter returns a filter that matches the most recent N cells in each column.

// CellsPerRowOffsetFilter returns a filter that skips the first N cells of each row, matching all subsequent cells.

// CellsPerRowLimitFilter returns a filter that matches only the first N cells of each row.
```

`LatestNFilter` has been around for a while but the other two are new.